# Required request body is missing in Spring when Angular Post call is sent

Tags: angular, spring

In my Angular application I'm trying to create a POST request, with a json body, that will be sent to my Spring Restful back-end; I have created a service in Angular to handle the API Post method but when I try to send the request, I obtain this error in my front-end console:

`core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/center/search_1/page/0", ok: false, …}`

and this error in my back-end console:

`Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.data.domain.Page`

This is the code of my service in Angular:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FirstQuery} from '../../../_responseModels/firstQuery/first-query';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {stringify} from 'querystring';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiCenterSearch1Service {

  apiURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/center/search_1/page/0';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getFirstQuery(body: JSON): any {

    return  this.httpClient.post<FirstQuery[]>(this.apiURL, JSON.stringify(body),
      {
        headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        // observe: 'response'
      });
  }

}
```

and this is a part of the code of a component that triggers the API call:

```
funcThis.apiCenterSearch1Service.getFirstQuery(JSON.parse(jsonRequest)).subscribe(
              res => {
                console.log(res);
              });
```

I've already tested my Spring API through Insomnia (an API tester application) and it works without any problems (and I also checked that the JSON required by the back-end is well formatted so I don't think that the problem is this).

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FirstQuery} from '../../../_responseModels/firstQuery/first-query';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {stringify} from 'querystring';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiCenterSearch1Service {

  apiURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/center/search_1/page/0';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getFirstQuery(body: any): any {

    return  this.httpClient.post<FirstQuery[]>(this.apiURL, body,
      {
        headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        // observe: 'response'
      });
  }

}
```

And your service code should be like

```
this.apiCenterSearch1Service.getFirstQuery(jsonRequest).subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this code. Problem could be that your backend wants a json object but you are sending a string.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FirstQuery} from '../../../_responseModels/firstQuery/first-query';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {stringify} from 'querystring';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiCenterSearch1Service {

  apiURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/center/search_1/page/0';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getFirstQuery(body: Object): any {

    return  this.httpClient.post<FirstQuery[]>(this.apiURL, body,
      {
        headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        // observe: 'response'
      });
  }

}
```

Service

```
funcThis.apiCenterSearch1Service.getFirstQuery(jsonRequest).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have completely fixed this issue adding to my back-end application the @CrossOrigin annotation in all the API entry points in order to enable CORS policy; so it was not a front-end problem